# "Prove that if $G$ is a group, then $\{x \in G : x^2 =e \}$ is a subgroup of $G$": is that correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My teacher left this exercise:

> "Prove that if $G$ is a group, then $\{x \in G : x^2 =e \}$ is a subgroup of $G$"

but I don't know if it's correct, I have seen similar exercises like that

> "if $x^2 = e $ for all $x \in G$ then $G$ is abelian",

and in this case if $G$ is abelian then the proof is fairly simple but my teacher didn't say $G$ was abelian, so I'm not sure if that statement is true or if he forgot to say that $G$ is abelian.

I have tried to found a counterexample (if it exists) but haven't found any.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is always true because in all groups, there exists an identity $e$, so for $x= e$, $x^2= e^2 = e$.  So, there is always the trivial subgroup of G consisting of  one element such that $x^2 = e^2 = e$

Comment: If $\{x \in G: x^2 = e\}$ is a group at all, it must be Abelian.  But you don't know that it *is* a group.  If you have a group $H\subset G$ where all $x \in H$ are $x^2 = e$ you don't know that there aren't *OTHER* $y$ so that $y^2 =e$ that *aren't* in $H$ nor that all such elements form a group.

Comment: @fleablood: I don’t think youir claim is true. Say $K$ is a nonabelian group of order $27$ and exponent $3$, and let $G=C_2\times K$. The group is definitely not abelian. But the elements of order dividing $2$ are exactly the elements of $C_2\times\{e\}$, which is certainly a subgroup. If $G$ is abelian, the set is a subgroup, but the set could be a subgroup even if the group is not abelian.

Comment: And it doesn't matter if $G$ is abelian or not.  The statement is true either way.  (Non-abelian groups can have abelian subgroups).  But $G$ being abelian *doesn't* make the proof any easier.  Just because $G$ can have a subroup where all elements are $e$ when squared doesn't mean the group will have *all* such elements or that all such elements will form a group.

Comment: @fleablood: I think you are confusing the query of whether the group in which everything is taking place ($G$) is abelian, with with whether the set of elements of exponent $2$ forms a subgroup and if so, that this is abelian. It’s confusing... If $G$ is abelian, then the set forms a subgroup; the set may form a subgroup in nonabelian groups (and of course, if it is a subgroup, then that subgroup is abelian).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  ???????  and $C_2 \times \{e\}$ is abelian, isn't it?

Comment: @fleablood: “it must be abelian”: “it”=the group $G$ in which everything is taking place, or “it”=the subgroup you are creating made up of elements of exponent $2$, if it is a subgroup? Again: confusing phrasing on your part, I think.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin there is utterly no reason to assume the supergroup $G$ is abelian or not and it want effect the proving of this statement in any way.  Point is $\{x| x^2 = e\}$ is certainly commutative and *if* it is a group it is abelian.  but whether $G$ is or isn't abelian doesn't affect how we would go about proving $\{x|x^2= e\}$ is a group.  So I'm not sure what your point is or what you think I am confusing.

Comment: @fleablood: *If* $G$ is abelian, then the set is **always** a subgroup. If $G$ is *not* abelian, then the set may or may not be a subgroup. For a *specific* group it may not matter, but for an *arbitrary*, non-given group, it certainly does matter whether $G$ is abelian or not. That’s why you are being confusing. The OP is talking about how whether $G$ itself is abelian would settle the problem, and is unsure whether $G$ being abelian was somehow left out.

Comment: Clearly in the sentence "If $\{x \in G: x^2 =e\}$ is a group at all, it must be Abelian" the "IT" is obviously referring to $\{x\in G: x^2=e\}$ and not to $G$.  $\{x\in G: x^2=e\}$ is the subject of the clause.  $G$ is nowhere mentioned in the sentence at all.

Comment: @fleablood: The OP talks about the abelianness of $G$, not of the subset-possibly-subgroup. Whether $G$ is abelian or not *totally* affects the proof of whether the set is a group or not, in that if $G$ is abelian the answer is “definitely yes”, and if $G$ is not abelian the answer is “not necessarily; sometimes yes and sometimes not”. I think we have a clear case of you knowing exactly what you meant and assuming everyone else can glean that from your words. I certainly could not. And last I checked, $G$ is mentioned in $\{x\in G\mid x^2=e\}$. When I read that, I certainly mention $G$.

Comment: ... and also “this statement.” I understand that to mean “$\{x\in G\mid x^2=e\}$ is a subgroup”. You seem to refer to “if $\{x\in G\mid x^2=e\}$ is a group, then that group is abelian.” Again, miscommunication based on implicit subjects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A reflection of the plane has order $2$, but the composite of two reflections in intersecting lines is a rotation, which does not necessarily have order $2$ ...

Comment: Inside the unitary group $U(2)$?  or is there a simpler group?

Comment: There  is no requirement that an element in G has order two, only that an element squared is equal to e, the identity.  Surely even in your latter group, $e^2 = e$, correct?  And $\{e\}\subseteq G$ in any group G$, correct.

Comment: $x^2=e$ doesn’t mean “order 2”. It means “order dividing $2$”. You should phrase that better.

Comment: An example of this is in the symmetries of an equilateral triangle, so the group $D_3$.

Comment: @Shaun: aka, $S_3$, i.e., the example DonAntonio gives.

Comment: Indeed, @ArturoMagidin, the two groups are isomorphic, but the argument in this answer is particular to $D_3$ as defined through symmetries.

Answer (score 7):

A probably simple counterexample: in $\;S_3\;$ , we have that $\;(12)^2=(13)^2=1\;$ , yet $\;(12)(13)=(132)\;$, and $\;(132)^2\neq1\;$ , so that the set $\;\{x\in G\;|\;x^2=e\}\;$ isn't even closed...